# Why doesn't console.log() take a snapshot of the passed variables?

Tags: javascript, debugging, console

I've ran into some really weird behavior with javascript today. I think I got it somehow figured out now, but I'd like to know if what I think is going on is really happening or if there is some other magic involved. So this is my code:

```
    var SomeObject = {};

    SomeObject.foo = function(a, b) {
       var baz = this.bar(a, b);
       console.log(baz);
       console.log(baz.left);
       SomeObject.magicalStuff(baz);
    };

    SomeObject.bar = function(a, b) {
        return {left: a-b, top: b-a};
    };

    SomeObject.magicalStuff = function(position) {
        position.left = 0;
    };

    SomeObject.foo(100, 50);
```

[The code at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UNWEp/)

The output of this is something like (depending on the browser):

```
> Object
50
```

If you expand the "Object" (in Chrome, Safari or Firefox (Firebug) what you get is:

```
> Object
    left: 0
    top: -50
```

Whereas I would expect:

```
> Object
    left: 50
    top: -50
```

What I think is going on is that console.log() really just "posts" a reference to the console, which gets read once you click on the "expand" symbol. But doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose of console.log() as a debugging instrument?
I always expected console.log() to "snapshot" the stuff I pass to it. It is really surprising to see a statement which comes after the actual console.log() change the output of that very console.log() call.

Or is there something else going on?

**Edit:** I'm also wondering if there is a sound reason for browser developers to implement console.log like this (I guess there is one, otherwise it wouldn't be consistent across major browsers).

Comment: See https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35801

Comment: @Roatin Marth: I see. But why do they say: "We can't clone object upon dumping it into the console". What technical difficulties occur that I am not able to see? :)

Comment: This is often seen when you try to log an event, since all events are a single object, you're usually looking at the latest mousemove event.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is `console.dir()` for what you want in Firebug.

In general, it is not possible to print *every* level of nested properties, since objects can contain circular references like `var a = {}; var b = {a: a}; a.b = b;`

Implementing a perfect `clone` method is very hard - I guess it would have to basically just dump the whole memory, and logging would take awfully long. Think about `console.log(window)`...

Comment: You've got a point there. Is there something similar for Webkit browsers such as Safari and Chrome?

Comment: I don't think so. As the [above-mentioned bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35801) suggests, this is a wontfix, and sure enough Firefox's `console.dir()` just pushes the problem to the next level

Comment: Please note that `console.dir` may not work in Chrome. Here's a comparison of solutions - http://jsfiddle.net/luken/M6295/ - try running it in Chrome.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, this is what's going on. I would guess it's done to minimize the overhead of `console.log()` calls. Things could get out of control if every object was deep cloned for every log call.

When I need to workaround this, I either `JSON.stringify()` or shallow clone the object before passing it to `console.log()`.

Comment: Yeah guess you're right. Nevertheless I think that, console.log() being a debug feature and all, it should deep clone. That would be less surprising at least ;)

Comment: JSON.stringify can have problems with HTML elements, since they have circular references. In that case I used outerHTML of the element.

Answer (score 6):

I've also seen this behavior and it sure looks like a reference is posted. To get around this I used the [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method in [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) on the things I wanted to log.

Comment: +1 For a good workaround. But I'm also wondering why console.log is implemented like this.

Comment: I guess Nathan's answer about the overhead can have something to do with it.