# Why 'this' is not empty in function Constructors in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
function Person(name){
  console.log(this);
  this.firstname=name;
}

var sam=new Person("Sam");
console.log(sam);
```

Output is -
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QKpF.png)

When a new Object is created, initially this should point to an empty object.
Why it has the updated response?

Comment: `Output is - Response` - how can the output be "Response" ... surely it's a "Person" object

Comment: @JaromandaX, it's a link to an image.

Comment: I know ... why couldn't the OP put that in the question

Comment: `Response` is a hyperlink showing that the object firstname has been console logged before it has been set in the code.

Comment: console.log can be misleading ... try `console.log(JSON.stringify(this))` and  `console.log(JSON.stringify(sam));` to get a true snapshot

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Google Chrome console.log() inconsistency with objects and arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175017/google-chrome-console-log-inconsistency-with-objects-and-arrays), and [Webkit bug 35801](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35801).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [console.log() shows the changed value of a variable before the value actually changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284663/console-log-shows-the-changed-value-of-a-variable-before-the-value-actually-ch)

Comment: by the time chrome process it in dev tools constructor is already finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press the 'dropdown' icon in chrome console to inspect the object, it will -then- start evaluating the object itself at that memory location. So at the moment you press it, the property `firstname` is already filled.

If you try:

```
console.log(this.firstname);
```

You will see:

> undefined
>
> Sam

You can also try it using:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this))
```

This will disable the ability to navigate through the object though. If it's just a plain object you can do this:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Firefox logs

```
Object {  } 
Object { firstname: "Sam" }
```

So, your browsers console is lying to you