# Typescript returns undefined on object

Tags: angular, typescript, pouchdb

I have the following code. I pull and object from Express Pouchdb then loop through the `_attachments` key to pull all the attachments. I have two attachments: "index" and "toc". Fun part is "index" returns it's "data" property fine but this one keeps failing and I have no idea why. This is how I have set the "toc" to my article object.

```
Object.keys(new_article['attachments']).map((at) => {
    this.articleStore.getAttachment(new_article['id'],at).then ((res) => {
        new_article.attachments[at]['data'] = res.toString();
    });
});

if (new_article['attachments'].hasOwnProperty('toc')) {
    console.log(new_article['attachments']['toc']) //Line #27 in screenshot
    console.log(new_article['attachments']['toc'].data) //Line #28 in screenshot
    new_article.toc = new_article['attachments']['toc']['data'];
}
```

Here's the screenshot of the console:
[image: screenshot of console]

The same object from PouchDB:

```
{
  "_id": "8c0f586b-020b-4832-bcde-945421c22a2e",
  "description": "Getting the Gist of Markdown's Formatting Syntax",
  "author": "John Gruber",
  "title": "Getting the Gist of Markdown's Formatting Syntax",
  "date": "4/15/2017",
  "_attachments": {
    "index.md": {
      "digest": "md5-PjR3R2K+KdpgLy/ye5wgAA==",
      "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
      "length": 8373,
      "revpos": 5,
      "stub": true
    },
    "toc": {
      "digest": "md5-heDcEdGg7nzo0OKe/30YxQ==",
      "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
      "length": 130,
      "revpos": 6,
      "stub": true
    }
  },
  "_rev": "8-167fdf2e930304927c5e2fc4e371b123"
}
```

The whole project here => https://github.com/flamusdiu/micro-blog/tree/dev

**Edit 1**

`_attachments` is remapped to `attachments` when I pull the object from pouchdb. Updated the code to show the lines above it.

**Edit 2**
Returning the value from the async call works fine. There is nothing wrong with that part of it. Seems that it's chaining that to my second call is what fixed it. See answer below.

Comment: is it `attachments` or `_attachments`? I think you should use `_attachments` according to your json data.

Comment: Oops, when I assign it to my local model, I remap it, however that doesn't work either.

Comment: so you mean to say `//Line #28 in screenshot` line is undefined?

Comment: Yeah, so the first `console.log()` shows the whole object but the second `console.log()` shows undefined.

Comment: This is the "closest" location to even reference that object. I was doing this elsewhere in the code but moved the code to figure out what was going on. Not sure if it matters but this inside an Angular 4.x project.

Comment: Have you tried replacing ['data'] with .data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: [Google Chrome console.log() inconsistency with objects and arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175017/google-chrome-console-log-inconsistency-with-objects-and-arrays)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Not having an issue returning from a sync call otherwise my object would be undefined.

Comment: @Andreas that's and interesting read. I'll have to keep that in mind.

Comment: `.getAttachment()` is asynchronous (hence the `.then(...)`) - as the complete [API of PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/api.html) and which is why `new_article['attachments']['toc'].data` is `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DB query is an asynchronous call, the assignments in the loop are not executed before the if at the end. Try this:

```
Promise.all(Object.keys(new_article['attachments']).map((at) => {
    return this.articleStore.getAttachment(new_article['id'],at).then ((res) => {
        new_article.attachments[at]['data'] = res.toString();
    });
})).then(() => {
    if (new_article['attachments'].hasOwnProperty('toc')) {
        console.log(new_article['attachments']['toc']) //Line #27 in screenshot
        console.log(new_article['attachments']['toc'].data) //Line #28 in screenshot
        new_article.toc = new_article['attachments']['toc']['data'];
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, then, that was it, sigh. Yeah, now I just need to get it push to the right spot ... lol. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like that fixes this problem but doesn't fix my original issue (which is why I went to try this). I cannot pull the "toc" out of the object. No matter where or what I do it's ALWAYS undefined. I get it: async problem but I am clueless to how to fix it. /sigh