# Chrome console.log() prints a number as a float and NaN

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Odd Chrome Behaviour

[image]

I'm experiencing a situation where `console.log()`'ing an array displays all the values correctly, but then expanding that array in chromes view gives completely different values.

See the picture for the behavior.

Comment: I feel like it's this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175017/google-chrome-console-log-inconsistency-with-objects-and-arrays Does the array change after it's logged?

Comment: It was an object reference issue. I made a copy of the object I was parsing and it fixed the issue. I guess the values inside the array were actually just referencing to something that's changing elsewhere in my code. That was a doozy.

Answer (score 0):

It was an object reference issue. I made a copy of the object I was parsing and it fixed the issue. I guess the values inside the array were actually just referencing to something that's changing elsewhere in my code.