# javascript object: access to properties

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I try to access to a javascript object property but there is a difference between what I get and what I see into the console.

Here is a debug of my object. On the console, when it displays only one line, I see:

```
s {longitude: 0.1367152479042797, latitude: 0.8081125973585543, height: 638}
```

But when I click on the line to show the details I see:

```
s {longitude: 0.1367152479042797, latitude: 0.8081125973585543, height: 638}

    height:764.1600000000001

    latitude:0.8081125973585543

    longitude:0.1367152479042797

    __proto__:Object
```

The value I'm looking for is the **height**. It's 638 in the s{..., **height: 638**} but **764.1600000000001** when I look the details.

The "correct" value is **764....** but how to access to this value? If I ask myObject.height, I get **638**.

I'm lost. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: can you show us the code that creates this object

Comment: @Aluan Haddad the correct value.

Comment: I'll take a stab into the dark and say it's a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175017/google-chrome-console-log-inconsistency-with-objects-and-arrays); if that's not it, give us a complete reproducible example.