# Array Behaviour in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome

I tried executing the code in Chrome Developer Console and i got this odd result which am not able to understand

```
var arr = [[2,2]];console.log('Array is',arr);arr[0] = [3,3]
```

The output i got after executing this is

`Array is [[3,3]]`

The assignment should happen after the `console.log` had been executed.But it magically happened before that.

To clarify i tried running the same code in [JsBin](https://jsbin.com/cahilon/edit?js,console).However in JSBin i got the expected out which is

`Array is [[2,2]]`

However this code yields expected result in chrome

`var arr = [2,2];console.log('Array is',arr);arr[0] = 3;console.log(arr)`

Output
`Array is [2,2] [3,2]`

Can someone help me understand this.

Comment: asynchronous javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Chrome console.log() inconsistency with objects and arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175017/google-chrome-console-log-inconsistency-with-objects-and-arrays)

Comment: Did not understand that @PetIbaño.What part of the code is Async in this.Please,Can you help me understand?

Comment: Javascript [asynchronous](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript#module-asynchronouscode)

Comment: the console lies - objects in the console are not "static" - they represent the current state of the object - so it's not really "Array behaviour" you are seeing, it's "console behaviour" you don't understand

Comment: chrome console is actually helpful ... when you "open" the object, a little blue `i` appears ... hover over it, and see the message ***"value below was evaluated just now"*** - see how chromes lying console at least tries to tell the truth :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Guess this is the case with all developer consoles.Firefox also gave the same result

Comment: yes, but my point was Firefox doesn't tell you it's lying, Chrome does

Comment: @SunilHari I added answer, hope it help you to understand in the primitive value assignment and object reference assignment. Hope, it will work as per the expectation. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is because chrome puts the value of the variable assignment in the console, when you initialize / declare a variable. This is an expected behavior.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that is happening, just expand the Array is [Array[2]] and you would be surprised

Comment: Arrays are basically references and clicking on the > symbol, just triggers a evaluation and it fetches the values then, because its a reference you see all the values associated. Its perfectly valid and reasonable.

Comment: @Sreekanth Can u tell me then why same thing is not happening in this case `var arr = [2,2];console.log('Array is',arr);arr[0] = 3;console.log(arr)`

Comment: So when is it printing for the first time ,i prints correctly unlike the first one

Comment: you also have changed the value of arr from array of array to array of objects.[[2,2]] is not same as [2,2] and the same concept of references would apply here. arr = [[2,2]], arr[0] is a reference , where as [2,2] its not a reference, its a value.

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays` are `objects` in JavaScript. Hence, `arr[0]` assignment after `console.log` assigning the array on the same reference where first `var arr = [[2,2]];` refer. Both `arr` variables refer to the same single object.

It happens only with objects but not with Primitive values like numbers.

**Example with primitive value**

```js
var arr = 1;
console.log('Array is',arr); // 1
arr++;
console.log('Array is',arr); // 2
```

**Example with objects :**

```js
var arr = [[2,2]];
console.log('Array is',arr);
arr[0] = [3,3]
```

**To avoid that you can use this :**

```js
var arr = [[2,2]];
console.log('Array is', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr)));
arr[0] = [3,3]
```