# Javascript JSON.stringify returns []

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am working with ReactJS and need to create an array to insert data, store it in localStorage, and view it later. I first create the array using `this.subscriptionsList = [];` I then use this method to retrieve the data.

```
  fetchNow = async (token, nextToken) => {
      fetch("somewebsite")
        .then(( unformattedData ) => {
          return unformattedData.json();
        })
        .then(( webData) => {
          for(let i = 0; i < webData.length; i++){
            this.subscriptionsList.push("someData");
          }
          if(webData.hasOwnProperty('token')){
            this.fetchNow(token, webData.token);
          }else{
            return;
          }
        })
      }
```

The function is not complete as it is not the focal point of my question. It works fine and pushes the correct data.

I retrieve the data using this method:

```
this.fetchNow(response.accessToken, "")
      .then( () => {
        console.log(this.subscriptionsList);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.subscriptionsList));
        localStorage.setItem("subscriptionsList", JSON.stringify(this.subscriptionsList));
        //console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("subscriptionsList")));
      })
```

The problem appears when I try to use `JSON.stringify`. Doing `console.log(this.subscriptionsList)` prints an array object with all the data inside of it as expected. However when I go to do `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.subscriptionsList))` it returns `[]`. Further, when printing the object itself, the property `length: 125` but when doing `console.log(this.subscriptionsList.length)` it returns `0` and when accessing using `this.subscriptionsList[0]` it returns `undefined`. I was reading the specifications and it appears as though JSON.stringify should work with a javascript array. Am I missing something react specific or is this just not available with JSON.parse?

```
https://gyazo.com/72aafe248ef61649a38c06d03fb3d830
https://gyazo.com/c2690b4392774fe4a98254a4d15f3a32
https://gyazo.com/e0793b5ec05da4259e16100f275da414
```

Comment: Could you please object structure screenshot

Comment: Not sure, Could you try to store `this.subscriptionsList` on a local variable and do operation on that.

Comment: I thought I knew what the issue was until you said logging the `length` property shows a different value than observing the `length` property, which is practically impossible. Are you sure of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *return* the promise chain in `fetchNow` or you can't chain to it later as you're trying. You'll also have to `return` the recursive `fetchNow` called inside `fetchNow` if you want it to be chained as well:

```
fetchNow = (token, nextToken) => {
  return fetch("somewebsite")
    .then(( unformattedData ) => {
    return unformattedData.json();
  })
    .then(( webData) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < webData.length; i++){
      this.subscriptionsList.push("someData");
    }
    if(webData.hasOwnProperty('token')){
      return this.fetchNow(token, webData.token);
    }
  })
}
```

`async` functions do not magically make asynchronous operations synchronous. They (1) return Promises and (2) allow for the `await` keyword. But since you're not using `await`, there's no need for `fetchNow` to be `async`, and since the `fetch` chain is already a `Promise`, you can return it directly without `async`.

If you *do* want to use `async` and `await`, it would make the code much flatter and easier to understand:

```
fetchNow = async (token, nextToken) => {
  const response = await fetch("somewebsite");
  const webData = await response.json();
  for(let i = 0; i < webData.length; i++){
    this.subscriptionsList.push("someData");
  }
  if(webData.hasOwnProperty('token')){
    await this.fetchNow(token, webData.token);
  }
  // async function will automatically return a Promise that resolves when the end is reached
}
```

Comment: As per @Jimmy comment `console.log(this.subscriptionsList) prints an array object with all the data inside of it as expected`.So,it's not  promise chain issue.

Comment: That's due to counter-intuitive `console.log` implementation - it's logging the *live* object, not the object as it *was* when it was logged.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175017/google-chrome-console-log-inconsistency-with-objects-and-arrays (it's not limited to Chrome, many more questions on this issue as well)

Comment: I thought of this at first as well but when I go to print the object it is the complete array. Am I  still missing something?

Comment: @Jimmy `console.log` unintuitively returns the *live* object, not the object at the moment it was logged. If you `stringify` the object beforehand, it'll more accurately represent the object's contents at that moment in time.

Answer (score 1):

This is what's happening....  What  `console.log(JSON.stringify(something))` does is that it serialises the immediate value and prints the serialised reference.(in other words it creates a cloned copy and prints the cloned copy not the original reference it won't wait for hoisted/mutated value). What `console.log(something)` does is that it refers to the original value and prints the actual result(mutated/hoisted) rather the immediate result. As your method being an asynchronous one you can clearly observe this. You can wait until the asyc call is done then you can push the actual variable to the localStorage. (Note that even local storage stores as serialised values)

Edit 1:-

```
let onComplete = (subscriptionsList) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(subscriptionsList));
    localStorage.setItem("subscriptionsList", JSON.stringify(subscriptionsList));
    //console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("subscriptionsList")));
}

fetchNow = async (token, nextToken, onComplete) => {
  fetch("somewebsite")
    .then(( unformattedData ) => {
      return unformattedData.json();
    })
    .then(( webData) => {
      for(let i = 0; i < webData.length; i++){
        this.subscriptionsList.push("someData");
      }
      if(webData.hasOwnProperty('token')){
        this.fetchNow(token, webData.token);
      }else{
        onComplete(this.subscriptionsList);
        return;
      }
    })
}

this.fetchNow(response.accessToken, "", onComplete)
  .then( () => {
    console.log("direct call ", this.subscriptionsList);
})
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are saying as I am not too familiar with hoisting and such in javascript. From what I understand you are saying that somehow the array becomes empty? This, however, isn't the case. The end result should have all of the data. I have included screenshots in my original post for more details

Comment: @Jimmy try the sample code in edit1 haven't tested it though. All you have to do is to wait for the async call to complete.

Comment: I see you and CertainPerformance were providing the same point but I believe his answer will help those in the future more as it demonstrates the importance of promise chaining so I accepted his answer. However, your answer does demystify the situation greatly and is also very important.