# Promise.all results are as expected, but individual items showing undefined

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

First of all, there are some issues with **console.log** in Google Chrome not functioning as expected. This is not the case as I am working in VSCode.

1. We begin with two **`async`** calls to the server.

   ```
   promise_a = fetch(url)
   promise_b = fetch(url)
   ```
2. Since **`fetch`** results are also promises, **`.json()`** will needed to be called on each item. The helper function *process* will be used, as suggested by a Stackoverflow user -- sorry lost the link.

```
        let promiseResults = []

        let process = prom => {
            prom.then(data => {
               promiseResults.push(data);
            });
         };
```

3. **`Promise.all`** is called. The resulting array is passed to **`.then`** where forEach calls *process* on item.json() each iteration and fulfilled promises are pushed to **`promiseResults`**.

```
        Promise.all([promise_a, promise_b])
          .then(responseArr => {
             responseArr.forEach(item => {
               process(item.json());
             });
          })
```

4. No argument is given to the final .then block because **`promiseResults`** are in the outer scope.  **`console.log`** show confusing results.

   ```
   .then(() => {
   console.log(promiseResults); // correct results
   console.log(promiseResults[0]); // undefined ?!?
   })
   ```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Chrome console.log() inconsistency with objects and arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175017/google-chrome-console-log-inconsistency-with-objects-and-arrays)

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with async/await syntax, I would suggest you not to use an external variable `promiseResults`, but return the results on the fly with this function:

```js
async function getJsonResults(promisesArr) {
    // Get fetch promises response
    const results = await Promise.all(promisesArr); 

    // Get JSON from each response promise
    const jsonResults = await Promise.all(results.map(r => r.json()));
    return jsonResults
}
```

This is usage example:

```js
promise_a = fetch(url1)
promise_b = fetch(url2)

getJsonResults([promise_a, promise_b])
   .then(theResults => console.log('All results:', theResults))
```

Use `theResults` variable to extract necessary results.

Comment: Great! Was glad to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it looks the array loop is not going properly in the promise env.
Specifically: the promiseResults is filled after you are logging.

```
var resultAll = Promise.all([promise_a, promise_b])
  .then(responseArr => {
     return Promise.all(responseArr.map(item => return item.json()));
  });

resultAll.then(promiseResults => {
   console.log(promiseResults);
});
```

Comment: I think it should be `Promise.all(responseArr.map(item => process(item.json())))`

Comment: ya that should be the proper way, didn't try what i wrote but, Promise.all also takes usual array as iterable, not needed to be promise array.

Comment: This solution also works, and I love the simplicity of using Promise.all twice. Pushing to the external array was the wrong approach. Much thanks!