# Why is a pushed object not being shown in the console?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am adding a String and an array to an already created array `myArray` using `push`. However, when I print the updated `myArray` in the console after pushing, I only see the String added to `myArray`, not the added array, in `myArray`’s content. (The content is seen when I press the little arrow next to the `myArray` array in the console.) The added array isn’t being taken into account in the length of the updated `myArray` either. Why is this?

Note: The added array isn’t shown to be in the updated `myArray`, but when I `pop` the last element from the updated `myArray`, the array that was added (the one of interest) is returned. So it seems to be stored in `myArray` but not technically? What is going on?

My code:

```js
var myArray = [1, 2, 3];

myArray.push('Jacob', ['Brandy', 2]);
console.log(myArray);

var removedValue = myArray.pop();

console.log(removedValue);
```

Current output:

```
Array(5) [ 1, 2, 3, "Jacob", (2) […] ]
    0: 1
    1: 2
    2: 3
    3: "Jacob"
    length: 4
    <prototype>: Array []
```

Expected output:

```
Array(5) [ 1, 2, 3, "Jacob", (2) […] ]
    0: 1
    1: 2
    2: 3
    3: "Jacob"
    4: ["Brandy", 2]
    length: 5
    <prototype>: Array []
```

Comment: Added a snippet for you and it's not showing the problem. Where are you logging this? Oh, i see it now in the Chrome console. Chrome logs live arrays so if you don't expand it before mutating it it will show the mutated array

Comment: `console.log`, depending on platform, is a *live view* of an object that updates as it is mutated. If you want a *snapshot* of the state of an object at a particular point in time, use `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))`

Comment: @pilchard I'm using Firefox Web Developer tools

Comment: ...and that would be why.

Comment: see: [console.log() inconsistency with objects and arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175017/google-chrome-console-log-inconsistency-with-objects-and-arrays)

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm new to JavaScript. Can you explain why using Firefox's Web Dev tools is the problem.

Comment: It's not a problem, but you have to be aware of how it logs data

Comment: @hsivru For the reason I already said: logging an object to the console in dev tools doesn't print a snapshot of the value of an object at a point in time, it gives a *live view* of the object that updates as the state changes. When you use `.pop()` it alters the *previous* `console.log`