# Google Chrome's console.log() prints DOM nodes inconsistently

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

Not a duplicate of [Google Chrome console.log() inconsistency with objects and arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175017/google-chrome-console-log-inconsistency-with-objects-and-arrays), since this question is not about objects and arrays.

---

Here is a simple HTML page:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>

  <script>
    for (const div of document.querySelectorAll("div")) {
      console.log(div);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Sometimes the results are shown as they presumably should:

[image]

and sometimes as if I used `console.dir()` instead of `console.log()`:

[image]

Rarely, I get a mix:

[image]

When I tried to create the [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) shown above, I removed the `<link>`, as it didn't seem to be related to the problem. However, after removing it, the inconsistency disappeared, so I restored it and tried to minimize the CSS itself, to the point where `style.css` is currently *completely* empty. So somehow the mere presence of the `<link>` tag seems to be at least related to the problem.

Is there a reason for this behavior, or is it a bug?

Comment: In my experience this can depend on at which point you open the console, i.e. if I open it after the content has already been logged it isn't formatted as nicely

Comment: In my experience this mostly happens when the browser is still parsing the DOM. Hence the issue can shows up when (for example) you add a stylesheet.

Comment: @Reyno Well, since the `div`s *are* printed, doesn't it mean that the DOM (or at least the relevant part of it) is already loaded when the script is executed?

Comment: I can duplicate OPs results. @MarcesEngel, I had the console open during multiple refreshes and it doesn't seem related to when you open the console. @Reyno, I thought the same thing, but wrapping the provided JS in a document event listener for `DOMContentLoaded` and printing `document.readyState` with each div also showed no correlation (I tried these tests independently and together).

Comment: Notice that during the rare instance you get a mix of outputs, you get collapsable objects before you get the HTML dump. I think what's happening is that rendering and the javascript engine are in different threads and at some point they sync up and settle. BEFORE they settle, javascript objects are printed. You can uncollapse each div and see all the javascript visible properties. AFTER they settle, the raw HTML is printed. If you use a timeout and an event listener to fire the code a small amount of time after the `DOMContentLoaded` event fires, then it ALWAYS prints the HTML.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn - I think your investigation deserves to be in an answer.

Comment: I was writing up my answer just now and I was trying to recreate my results but I ended up with a split output situation that output HTML style divs before it output the JSON style divs. That blows my theory out of the water because it should only work the other way around. I thought the renderer was updating the JS engine with DOM hints not taking them away.

Comment: For me this inconsistency also happens with `console.dirxml()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a bug nor a feature but more of a trade-off. I gave an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73380790/13993967) to a similar question about "how to", thus is was short. Here is about "why", so it needs more "academic" explanation.
It is related to how the [Chromium DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/api/) logging work in union with the [Blink](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1aitSOucL0VHZa9Z2vbRJSyAIsAz24kX8LFByQ5xQnUg/edit) engine, here is a simplified scenario for a DOM node:

```
console.log(document.querySelector('div'));
```

`Blink V8::console.log` `-> IPC ->` `Chromium Process` `-> IPC ->` `DevTools front-end fork`

That is, [V8](https://v8.dev/docs) executes `console.log` method implemented by Blink, which triggers a message for `DevTools`. That message is handled by `IPC` which in Blink is mainly asynchronous.
Once `DevTools Console` receives a `Node` object it must inspect the `DOM Renderer` to sync with it's actual *render tree*, so that when hovering on the node in the console the `Renderer` would highlight the node in browser page, so there it is:

`DevTools inspect` `-> IPC ->` `Chromium Process` `-> IPC ->` `Blink DOM Render`

Here is the problem, since the `DOM Renderer` is busy with synchronous style loading, in this specific case the [render-blocking resource](https://web.dev/render-blocking-resources/#which-urls-get-flagged-as-render-blocking-resources) is `link` element, so it fails to respond timely and instead of *render tree* representation the console fallback to *object* representation of it, doing so instead of just showing a *string* representation gives the possibility to inspect that node anyway, a sane trade-off, albeit without the commodity of seeing it's *mirror* reference.
Additionally, other peculiarities of `DevTools Console` may be noted:

- It does not really matter which `console` method was called, as they are mainly aliases for *log level* definition and not for special handling of object inspection, so `console.error` behaves the same for that reason.
- `DevTools inspect` is issued only if `Console` tab is active or becomes active. So while it may show a *object* representation of node when performing the tests with an active `Console` tab, when performing them while being on another tab, let's say `Performance`, then switching to `Console` we can see those nodes appearing one by one as *render tree*, since by that time the `DOM Render` will be accessible.
- A common myth about logged objects is that they mutates in the console when they are mutated by the JS runtime. Well, they are not. The `Console` creates a static "fingerprint" of object only for *current level* tree. It then creates a deeper tree on demand, when manually unfolding it, so it just uses for that new tree the current values which may give false impressions that it mutates the *log*.

I modified a bit the initial example, to be more like a "real" application, also to reveal the above behavior. Additionally, for more stress on render engine, it may be played with a `x4` or `x6` CPU throttling in the `DevTools Performance` tab.

```html
<head>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>
      console.log('DOMContentLoaded'));
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>

  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script>
    for (const div of document.querySelectorAll("div")) {
      console.log(div);
    }

    let i = 1000, div, divs = [], ids = [];
    while (i--) {
      div = document.createElement('div');
      div.textContent = new Date().toISOString();
      document.body.appendChild(div);
      if (!(i % 100)) {
        const id = {id: i};
        ids.push(id);
        divs.push(div);
        console.log(id, {div}, div);
      }
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      for (const id of ids)
        id.id = Math.random();

      for (const div of divs) {
        div.style.color = 'red';
        const child = document.createElement('div');
        child.textContent = 'OK';
        div.appendChild(child);
      }
    }, 1000);
  </script>
</body>
```

**NOTE:** The `console.log` results must be checked in the `DevTools` not in the *playground* here, as it just parses the arguments of `console.log` with it's own parser and has nothing to do with real `console.log` behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I've read the comments by [@Corey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160527/corey-ogburn), and yet I want to point you to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log) which contradicts what Corey said.

> Please be warned that if you log objects in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox what you get logged on the console is a reference to the object, which is not necessarily the 'value' of the object at the moment in time you call console.log(), **but it is the value of the object at the moment you open the console.**

now as per the difference between `console.log()` and `console.dir()`.
besides the difference in the way they print the DOM element, another differentiator is as follows:

> console.log gives special treatment to DOM elements, whereas console.dir does not. This is often useful when trying to see the full representation of the DOM JS object.

possible solution / another test case is, by
yet again, referencing the docs, to log DOM elements is not `console.log(obj)`, but actually `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))` (and this actually the recommended way to log objects to console).

the logic behind this recommendation is that in this way you can be sure you are seeing the value of obj at the moment you log it. Otherwise, many browsers provide a live view that constantly updates as values change. This may not be what you want.

Comment: Thank you. As far as I can understand, though your answer does suggest an alternative way of printing DOM elements, it does not address the inconsistent results when using `console.log()`. Is it a bug or a feature? If it's supposed to happen, why and when? Thanks again.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.