# Weird array output TS/Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I'm trying to sort data from API for chart, so I need to filter it based on currency name so I can get their rates.

Algo is working properly but I'm getting weird output in my browser and chart also.

Output from *tempRates* in browser looks like this: `[7.4429, 7.4429, 7.4392, 7.4392]` which is the correct output.

But when I expand the same array in the browser console I get this output:

```
(4)[7.4429, 7.4429, 7.4392, 7.4392]
  0: 1
  1: 1
  2: 1
  3: 1
```

And that goes for all arrays.

But value of last array is `(4)[1, 1, 1, 1]` and that is the expected output.

```
Object.keys(data.rates).forEach((key) => {
 this.data.labels.push(key); // date
});

Object.values(data.rates).forEach((value) => {
 tempCurrency = Object.keys(value)[i];

 Object.values(data.rates).forEach((rate) => {
   if (tempCurrency === Object.keys(rate)[i]) {
     tempRates.push(rate[tempCurrency]);
     //tempRates.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 100));
   }
 });
            
 console.log("log before push", tempRates);
 this.data.datasets.push({
  label: tempCurrency,
  data: tempRates,
  });
  i++;

  if (!(i === Object.keys(data.rates).length)) {
      tempRates.length = 0;
  }
});
```

I also have tried with random numbers and the output still has the same problem. All arrays have the value of last array.

[Console screen shoot](https://prnt.sc/Y1W6aXCsW1IZ)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Chrome console.log() inconsistency with objects and arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175017/google-chrome-console-log-inconsistency-with-objects-and-arrays)

Comment: @HarshSaini Problem is same in prepared data for chart.  All data arrays for chart have same value as last array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was change the `tempRates.length = 0;` to `tampRates = []`.

I just don't know what is the difference between those two solutions. I would be grateful if someone could explain it to me.