find() method not finding the correct item
I'm doing a uni project on an online course website like Udemy using VueJs. When I remove a course from the cart and trying to add it back to my courses array, the course.spaces is not being updated. I'm encountering an error where my find() and findIndex() functions are returning undefined when I console.log the variables they're stored in. Any help would be appreciated!
A course:
      { 
        id: 1,
        subject: "Algorithms",
        location: "London",
        price: 20,
        spaces: 5,
        thumbnail: "images/algorithms.png"
       }

removeFromCart(courseId) {
            const index = this.findCourseId(courseId, this.cart);

            if (index !== -1) {
                const quantity = this.cart[index].quantity;
                const originalCourse = this.findCourse(courseId, this.coursesCopy);

                this.cart.splice(index, 1);

                if (originalCourse) {
                    originalCourse.spaces += quantity;
                }
            }
            
            this.saveToStorage();
        }

I made two functions where one would find an object while the other finds the id of the object, and I used them in my removeFromCart() func:
findCourse(courseId, array) {
            const course = array.find(item => item.id === courseId);

            return course;
        },
findCourseId(courseId, array) {
            const index = array.findIndex(item => item.id === courseId);
            
            return index;
        }


This is about 300 lines of code but most of it is unrelated to the problem. Would you distill your example code down to a Minimal, Reproducible Example?

Sorry, I updated my question. I hope it's easier to understand.

The question doesn't contain code that can reproduce the problem. ". I'm encountering an error where" - please, quote errors instead of retelling them, they are more informative this way. "when I console.log the variables" - use a debugger, console should be the last resort, this is likely the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175017

What are you passing as courseId to the removeFromCart()-function? Would you please add console.log('courseId', typeof courseId); as the first line inside the removeFromCart-function and post the exact output as a comment? I have a suspicion what the error might be, but I need some more information here. I think courseId might be a string when it is being passed to removeFromCart.

Your code is not really clear enough @AFK, but I think the problem is with with the array you're performing the find or findIndex on. Try logging/printing the array variable. Just ensure the right variable is named array. Since you're using options API, maybe try this.array.find() if the variable is called array, use the name of the variable. e.g. this.coursesCopy.find() if it's inside options data or just coursesCopy.find()
