# Coffeescript / Javascript Why, do the objects in a cloned array seem to lose their references when passed to a method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript, clone, slice

I am cloning an array of objects using `slice()` but when I pass that cloned array into another method the array's contents are losing their references and become `undefined`.

```
class Chooser
  constructor: (@order, @items) ->
    # do stuff

  choose: ->
    console.debug "Choosing", @order.size, "from", @items.slice()
    @process(@order.size, @items.slice())
    # do stuff

  process: (count, items) ->
    console.debug "count", count
    console.debug "items", items
    console.debug "@items", @items
    # do recursive stuff that includes an items.shift()
```

The first `console.debug` gives me, as expected:

```
Choosing 10 items from [Item, Item]
```

where `Item` and `Item` are exactly what I expected.

But then the next `console.debug` lines give me

```
count 10
items [undefined x 2]
@items [Item, Item]
```

I understand that `@items.slice()` creates a *shallow* copy of `@items`, and as such the objects within the array are references to the same `Item` objects. The `Item` objects obviously still exist as they are still in the original `@items` array.

Why, do the objects in the cloned array seem to lose their references once within the `process` method?

See this [Working example of the problem converted to Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/k0quf8v2/)

Comment: Please post a link to an example running on jsfiddle, jsbin, codepen, requirebin or something like that and then tell us what you see and what you expect instead. It doesn't make a lot of sense to debug a problem that you say exists but others in the comments say it doesn't.

Comment: I've managed to reproduce the error but could not get the coffee script site to generate a sensible url.  see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k0quf8v2/) however which is converted to javascript from coffee script. It reproduces the error.

Comment: @DaveSag: I suggest copying the relevant code from the fiddle **into** the question, as the code there doesn't have the bit removing the entries from the array, which causes the problem with the console later. This ensures that questions remain useful for people in the future, as external links rot, and SO is meant to be essentially self-contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer for what is happening in your code:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24176638/635411

As you can see the slicing is working fine:

```js
var MyClass = (function() {
  
  function MyClass(items) {
    this.items = items;
  }
  
  MyClass.prototype.fn1 = function() {
    console.log(this.items);
    this.fn2(this.items.slice());
  };
  
  MyClass.prototype.fn2 = function(items){
    console.log(items);
  };
  
  return MyClass;
})();

new MyClass([{id:1, name:'a'}, {id:2, name:'b'}]).fn1();
```

What you are seeing is that your array is being shifted before you expanded it in the console. If you actually stringify the object you can see that it was successfully passed in.

```js
var MyClass = (function() {
  
  function MyClass(items) {
    this.items = items;
  }
  
  MyClass.prototype.fn1 = function() {
    console.log(this.items);
    this.fn2(this.items.slice());
  };
  
  MyClass.prototype.fn2 = function(items){
    console.log(items);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(items, null, 2));
    items.shift();
    items.shift();
  };
  
  return MyClass;
})();

new MyClass([{id:1, name:'a'}, {id:2, name:'b'}]).fn1();
```