# why array become blank after splitting into multiple small array?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

hello I have one a array $scope.name .I am spliting the array into small arrays .But after spliting the array .it become blank why ?
  actually I assigned the given array into temp variable and splite the temp variable .Again my $scope.name become blank why ?

here is my plunker 
  http://plnkr.co/edit/iUscrw0xclHSnsIWMMTM

```
    console.log("before");
    console.log($scope.name);
    var test=$scope.name;
     console.log("after");
      console.log($scope.name);
    console.log("test");
    console.log(test);
    var arrays = [], size = 3;

while (test.length > 0)
    arrays.push(test.splice(0, size));

console.log(arrays);
console.log("name");
    console.log($scope.name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are directly assigning object to other object, so that will cause change in any of the object will update other object value.
Use `angular.copy` instead of assigning object directly, that will  create a new clone copy of that object will returned.

```
 var test=angular.copy($scope.name);
```

[**Forked Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/InUq2gJR1oT2DFGt0Oqw?p=preview)

Comment: Why do the `console.logs` appear empty, even though they're executed before the while loop? Just wondering since this seems like really weird behaviour.

Comment: @Fissio look at this the same problem related to `console.log` are appearing to be printed late http://stackoverflow.com/a/11284702/2435473