# Javascript/Loopback - array.length returns 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loopback

I am using loopback to read list/array of customers. I stored customer array in $scope.customers.customerList. When I first log, the array seems fine but when I get its length, it seems to get lost because it returns 0. Why is that happen?

Here is my code:

```
    $scope.customers = { customerList: [] };

    var filter = {
           include: {
              relation: 'orders'
           }
    };

    $scope.customers.customerList = Customers.find({filter: filter});
    console.log($scope.customers.customerList);          //outputs array with length 21
    console.log($scope.customers.customerList.length);   //array length is 0
```

Link: [screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAosI.png)

Comment: Seems to be that 0 is a valid value, and certainly possible given your code, e.g. if the filter yeilds zero results.

Comment: It's possible the array is being modified after `console.log()` is called. The Dev Tool's Console is showing you the value as of when you look at it – "[*console.log() shows the changed value of a variable before the value actually changes*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284663/console-log-shows-the-changed-value-of-a-variable-before-the-value-actually-ch)." The `length` doesn't do the same because the number read from it is immutable. You might try `console.dir()` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [console.log() shows the changed value of a variable before the value actually changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284663/console-log-shows-the-changed-value-of-a-variable-before-the-value-actually-ch)

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly what [Jonathan Lonowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15031/jonathan-lonowski) has described. `Customers.find` which is created by [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) returns an empty array initially and when data is loaded it updates it. [By the time the Browser console prints it or when you open it, the results are already there.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284663/console-log-shows-the-changed-value-of-a-variable-before-the-value-actually-ch)

From Angular docs:

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method
>   immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on
>   isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing
>   reference is populated with the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Use the find method with callback function.

```
      $scope.customers = { customerList: [] };

var filter = {
       include: {
          relation: 'orders'
       }
};

Customers.find({filter: filter},function(customerList){
$scope.customers.customerList=customerList;

   console.log($scope.customers.customerList);          //outputs array with length 21
console.log($scope.customers.customerList.length); 
},function(error){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The find method in loopback accepts a callback and returns a promise. you can use either.

```
//callback
Customers.find({filter: filter}, function (err, customerList) {
  $scope.customers.customerList = customerList;
});

//Promise
Customers.find({filter: filter}).then(function(customerList) {
  //customerList is an array
  $scope.customers.customerList = customerList;
});
```

You can see in your output that the promise was resolved and gave the 21 elements. The length was 0 because the promise was not resolved at that point.