# Array acting weird?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var array = [{"x": 0}];
    array[0] = {"x": 10};
    console.log(array);
    array[0] = {"x": 20};
    console.log(array);
});
```

With this I expect the output in the console to be:

```
[
    {
        0: {"x": 10}
    }
]

[
    {
        0: {"x": 20}
    }
]
```

But instead it is:

```
[
    {
        0: {"x": 20}
    }
]

[
    {
        0: {"x": 20}
    }
]
```

Does anyone have any idea why? Am I missing something?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6nfdmt91/

Comment: Actually, the output is **not** what you wrote in your question.

Comment: The console is not a snapshot when logging arrays/objects .... it shows live objects that still have inheritance

Comment: *"With this I expect the output in the console to be"* <- what makes you think you'd have numeric object keys? All you should expect to see is something like `[{x: 10}]` or `[{x: 20}]`

Comment: @charlietfl Shouldn't the console log give the value of the current array?

Comment: ^-- that's exactly what the console is doing...

Comment: @LJa yes but if you modify same array after logging to console it will show live version...including changes

Comment: @GerardoFurtado how would I achieve what I want to achieve?

Comment: Duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284663/console-log-shows-the-changed-value-of-a-variable-before-the-value-actually-ch

Comment: Look at duplicate question links at top of the page

Comment: @snapjs I believe the question I chose as a duplicate is better, because it addresses the console.log issue explicitly.

Comment: @LJa what do you want to achieve? Keep the old state of an array? You can save it: https://jsfiddle.net/6nfdmt91/3/

Answer (score -5):

try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var array = [{"x": 0}];
 array[0] = {"x": 10};
 console.log(array);
 array[0].push({"x": 20});
 console.log(array);
});
```

Using Array.push() will "push" a new element.