# Object logged in console has length of 0 but is not empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension to modify HTML on a page. Here's what I've got:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Trello YouTube video embed",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Embeds YouTube video players in Trello card descriptions based on links in the card description",
  "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["embed.js"],
    "matches": ["https://trello.com/*"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }]
}
```

**embed.js**

```
var cardDesc = document.getElementsByClassName('current markeddown hide-on-edit js-card-desc js-show-with-desc');
console.log(cardDesc);
console.log('cardDesc === undefined : ' + (cardDesc === undefined).toString());
console.log('cardDesc[0] === undefined : ' + (cardDesc[0] === undefined).toString());
console.log('cardDesc.length : ' + cardDesc.length);
```

And here's a screenshot of the console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ytHJ.png

The problem is that the `cardDesc` is returning a length of `0` but I can clearly see an item in the `HTMLCollection`. Any suggestions of what I can do differently in order to manipulate the items in `cardDesc`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [console.log() shows the changed value of a variable before the value actually changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284663/console-log-shows-the-changed-value-of-a-variable-before-the-value-actually-ch)

Comment: Using `getElementsByClassName` will give you a live collection, the console may be showing you a rendered version based on data that is only available later

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 

`document.querySelectorAll('.current.markeddown.hide-on-edit.js-card-desc.js-show-with-desc')`

instead of

`document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Simply returns empty `NodeList []`

Comment: You have to remove the spaces between the class selectors. I.e. `.current.markeddown.hide-on-edit`…