# How to get circular data from JS object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm currently running `console.log` on a variable like so:

```
console.log(runnable);
```

When I look in the console I see this data:

[image]

I want to access the `runnable.err` key however the console returns `undefined`.

After this I tried to use `console.log(JSON.stringify(runnable));` however I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

When researching how to convert the circular structure all I can find is ways to parse the data safely without including the circular data. Is there any way I can access this data? Unfortunately I can't alter the data.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try targeting your error more precisely? `console.log(runnable.err.message)`

Comment: @Zenoo how can one log property message of undefined?

Comment: @LaurensMäkel Doesn't seem undefined to me in the Chrome DevTools, unless it is populated later on.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I had tried going a layer deeper like so `runnable.err.message` returns undefined.

Comment: @zenoo well op mentioned he tried logging err but it returned undefined, there is no way that err.message will be defined when err is undefined :/ .. I can see its in Dev tools showing up, but that's exactly op his question

Comment: How is this a duplicate? The question is an example of an XY problem (OP think they want to do X but actually wants to do Y).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what's happening here is that `runnable` doesn't have a `.err` property when you call `console.log(runnable)` but a `.err` property is added later.

Using console.log() on objects can behave strangely (showing the current state of the object instead of the state when logged). See [console.log() shows the changed value of a variable before the value actually changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284663/console-log-shows-the-changed-value-of-a-variable-before-the-value-actually-ch)

To test that hypothesis, try changing

```
console.log(runnable.err);
```

to

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(runnable.err);
}, 1000);
```

and see if it's no longer `undefined`.

Comment: You are right, this works! Thanks a lot.