# JavaScript object is wired?I don't know why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

this is the result when I run in node

[image]

this is the result when I run in chrome

[image]

Comment: Please post your code, not images

Comment: And what’s the issue? Chrome provides correct output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [console.log() shows the changed value of a variable before the value actually changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284663/console-log-shows-the-changed-value-of-a-variable-before-the-value-actually-ch)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284663/console-log-shows-the-changed-value-of-a-variable-before-the-value-actually-ch

Answer (score 0):

Nothing "weird" in Chrome, the a: "" reflect the actual value of the object which is indeed "" (not the one by the time you logged it).

If you put your mouse on the "i" it will say : "value below was evaluated just now)

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue at all in the output.

While the value is printed, value of "form.a" is 123. However the value of a is updated to "" in the code. Hence the behavior.