# Javascript object is empty when accesing throught its parent object in key iteration

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access to an object attribute with an autogenerated key, which means I have to iterate through its keys and access the parent object with the index. The problem comes when I console log the index is correctly fetched, but when I access the object attribute it returns an empty object (not undefined).

```
      console.log(detailArray)
      detailArray.forEach((detail) => {
        for(var i in detail) {
          if (detail.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
              console.log(i, detail[i])
          }
        }
      })
```

These are the values returned in the first console log

```
[
  {
    "2gC28U711o": {
      "number": "654324232",
      "operator": {
        "id": 0
      },
      "paymentModality": "contract",
      "action": "portability"
    }
  }
]
```

and these are the loop console log:

```
 2gC28U711o  {}
```

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**
This code is inside a function called in each success of several async calls, with a counter to verify that we enter here when all the calls have ended. Outside this function the loop works fine, but inside it doesn't

Thanks in advance.

```js
var detailArray = [
  {
    "2gC28U711o": {
      "number": "654324232",
      "operator": {
        "id": 0
      },
      "paymentModality": "contract",
      "action": "portability"
    }
  }
]

      detailArray.forEach((detail) => {
        for(var i in detail) {
          if (detail.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
              console.log(i, detail[i])
          }
        }
      })
```

Comment: Would be helpful for us to know what `detailArray` contains

Comment: the first console.log shows the contents of detailArray

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me

Comment: Make sure the web browser you use can handle es6 syntax

Comment: Object.keys() is better than the for loop.

Comment: Im testing it in both chrome and firefox, and the problem is that the same loop is done in other function and there it works fine, but here it doesn´t

Comment: Seems fine in the code, not sure what you are seeing that is different. The `console.log(i, detail[i])` shows up in my console fine.

Comment: don't know why, but changing `for(var i in detail)` with `for (let i in detail)` works for me in chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I found the error. Everthing comes from console.log not being that reliable when it comes to know the exact value of something in a loop. I made a JSON.stringify(detailArray) and it appeared empty as in the loop console.log, which means console.log was printing data not yet filled.

After some rearrangement the code now works fine.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284663/console-log-shows-the-changed-value-of-a-variable-before-the-value-actually-ch/11284675#11284675) was pretty usefull to find out what could be.