# React - Redux component not displaying array.length correctly despite component being rerendered on state change without mutating the state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Issue: I am using React with Redux store to manage my state. I want to display filters on a component. These filters will be returned from Tableau Javascript API. Based on the return from Tableau JavaScriptAPI I am updating the state in the store. The state is getting updated correctly with the right filters, which is also causing my component to update/ re-render. All good so far.

But when I am trying to access these filters (be it object using Object.keys() or array using array.length) from state.props, I am getting null array in return.

This is probably dues to incorrect use of Thunk/ Async Await.

Here is the code snippet

**Step 1: Calling the Action from React.** When I click a button, fetch dashboard action is called

```
class DashboardView extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    id = this.props.dashboardDetails.categoryID;
    console.log("Mounted");
    this.props.fetchDashboard(
      this.props.dashboardDetails.categoryURL,
      this.vizContainer
    );
  }
```

**Step 2A: Here's the fetchDashboard action:** 
within this action, I am creating filterNAmes array which I want to display on my component. I am making sing of Thunk here as my actions sends an API request to Tableau JavascriptAPI. The way I want it to work is once, we get response from the API, we will dispatch the viz to a reducer and the filterNames array to another action fetchFilter. Snippet attached.

```
export const fetchDashboard = (url, vizContainer) => async dispatch => {
  let filterNames = [];
  //  let titlesTemp = {};
  //const vizContainer = {};
  const options = {
    hideToolbar: true,
    onFirstInteractive: function() {
      let workbook = viz.getWorkbook();
      const activeSheet = workbook.getActiveSheet();
      activeSheet
        .getWorksheets()
        .get("Index")
        .getFiltersAsync()
        .then(function(filters) {
          for (let filter in filters) {
            let filterTitle = filters[filter].getFieldName();
            let filterName = {};
            filterName[filterTitle] = [];
            let len = filters[filter].getAppliedValues().length;
            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
              filterName[filterTitle].push(
                filters[filter].getAppliedValues()[i].value
              );
            }
            filterNames.push(filterName);
          }
        });
    }
  };
  let viz = await new window.tableau.Viz(vizContainer, url, options);
  dispatch({ type: "FETCH_DASHBOARD", payload: { viz } });
  console.log(filterNames, filterNames.length);
  return dispatch(fetchFilter(filterNames));
};
```

When I  console.log(filterNames, filterNames.length), the filterNames array has elements in it(which get evaluated later) but the filterNames.length return 0. I think this is the root cause of the issue. I want to dispatch the next action only when FilterNames is populated.

**Step 2B:**

```
export const fetchFilter = filterNames => {
  console.log("FETCH_FILTER action called", filterNames);
  return { type: "FETCH_FILTER", filterNames };
};
```

Assuming this is not the issue-
**Step 3: Reducer**

```
const fetchFilterReducer = (fetchFilter = [], action) => {
  if (action.type === "FETCH_FILTER") {
    console.log("fetchfilterreducercalled:", action.filterNames);
    return action.filterNames;
  }
  return fetchFilter;
};
```

This updates the State fetchFilter in the store correctly.

**Step 4:** Using the connect function, I am pulling the fetchFilter array in the property of the component.

```
class FilterDisplay extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
    if (this.props.selectionFilters.length !== 0) {
      console.log(this.props);
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log(this.props.selectionFilters.length);
    if (this.props.selectionFilters.length !== 0) {
      console.log("filter display updated");
      console.log(this.props);     
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>hey</div>; //<Tile></Tile>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log("first  filters in state:", state.fetchFilter);

  return {
    selectionFilters: state.fetchFilter
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FilterDisplay);
```

On my componentDidUpdate, I am getting length of selectionFilters array as 0.
This is not allowing me to display the contents of the array on my screen.

This is a lot to read but I could not fit it in a smaller description. 
Please let me know in case I need to add more details.

Thanks for all the help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot going on here and probably a better way to integrate with Tableau but in order to solve you problem I think you just need to move `dispatch(fetchFilter(filterNames));` inside the `then()` block in your `fetchDashboard` action.

```js
.then(function(filters) {
  // all that other code ...
  dispatch(fetchFilter(filterNames));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Its not working. Dispatch never gets executed, tried adding a console.log() as well and it did not execute at all. adding snippet in next comment

Comment: .then(function(filters) {
          for (let filter in filters) {
            let filterTitle = filters[filter].getFieldName();
            let filterName = {};
            filterName[filterTitle] = [];
            let len = filters[filter].getAppliedValues().length;
            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
              filterName[filterTitle].push(
                filters[filter].getAppliedValues()[i].value
              );
            }
            filterNames.push(filterName);
          }
        
          console.log(filterNames, filterNames.length);
        });

Answer (score 0):

In `fetchDashboard`, you could try to move `dispatch(fetchFilter(filterNames));` at the end of the `onFirstInteractive` function.

`new window.tableau.Viz(vizContainer, url, options)`  is not an async operation, which means that you are dispatching `fetchFilter` with an empty array (`console.log` does not help in this case, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284663/console-log-shows-the-changed-value-of-a-variable-before-the-value-actually-ch)).