# Object Assignment in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Error trying to
assignment objects in javascript

[image: Image of output]

```js
let info = {
  ID: '',
}

let ids = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"]

ids.forEach((i) => {
  info.ID = i
  console.log(info)
});
```

I expect the output of this code to be an object info with ID 1 to 4, but the actual output is info.ID = 4

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48969647/4350275

Comment: You're updating the property ID to equal whatever i is in the loop. Since "4" is last in the loop, info.id will equal "4".

Comment: `info.id = ids`, otherwise you are just rewriting I'd property each loop iteration.

Comment: It's unclear what result you expect. *"an object info with ID 1 to 4"* how can one object have one property with 4 different values at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the object. Simply use map on the array:

```js
let ids = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"]

let info = ids.map(i => ({ID: i}));

console.log(info);
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you are iterating over an array and assign the ID with the value of each item in the array.

If you want to assign the property ID with the array just use this:

```
let info = {
 ID : ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"]
} 

console.log(info);
```

It's unclear what you are trying to achieve with the forEach loop.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let ids = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"]
let info = {
    ID: ids
}
console.log(info);
```

Note: You just need to assign your local variable name to the object element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
let info = []

let ids = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"]

ids.forEach((i) => {
  info.push({ID : i})
  console.log(info)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need an array of `info` object.

```
let infos = []

let ids = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"]

ids.forEach((i) => {
  let info = {ID: i};
  infos.push(info);
});

infos.forEach((info) => console.log(info.ID));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just re-writing the ID over and over again. You should push new value of id always.

```
function solve() {
      let info = [];

      let ids = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'];

      for (const id of ids) {
        info.push({ ID: id });
      }

      console.log(info);
    }

    solve();
```