# Javascript objects returns different values for a field when printed individually or whole

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript line:

```
console.log({fieldMeta__value: fieldMeta.value, fieldMeta: fieldMeta});
```

As you can see, I am printing to console the object `fieldMeta` and, also, its field `value`. The problem is that its field `value` (`fieldMeta.value`) returns `1`, but the whole objects prints the content for `value` as `undefined`:

[image]

I am pretty sure I have some flaw in my logic, but I can't find it.

**EDIT**

I tried another approach for printing the values:

```
console.log(fieldMeta);
console.log(fieldMeta.value);
```

And I got the same result:
[image]

Comment: `fieldMeta__value` is just a label for `fieldMeta.value`

Comment: Im sorry but how is this possible? :)

Comment: Hover over the blue `i` and/or read https://stackoverflow.com/q/11284663/215552

Comment: Basically, you should use `console.dir` or `console.log(JSON.stringify(fieldMeta))` to see what the values are at the time the log occurs.

Comment: Like the others pointed to the other SO question and the answers there: Try ```console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(fieldMeta)))``` and see if it persists

Comment: @HereticMonkey I am not sure it is the same problem, because I don't change the value of the object field. I just prints different when printed individually than when printing the object as a whole

Comment: Does it print differently if you use `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: @HuLuViCa If you think you're not changing the value of the object field, please post a [mcve] that exhibits this behaviour. Maybe some code other than yours is changing the property.