# change value in a object Array in a for()

Tags: javascript, typescript

i want to update a value in a array of object in javascript.

```
export var headingLeistenbelegung = [
  [ {value: 'Projektnummer: ', style: styles.headerDarkBold},
    {value: '121466', style: styles.headerDark},
    {value: 'Projektbezeichnung: ', style: styles.headerDarkBold},
    {value: 'adsadköald', style: styles.headerDark},
  ],
  [
  ],
  [ {value: 'Server ID: ', style: styles.headerDarkBold},
    {value: '3', style: styles.headerDark},
    {value: 'Serverbezeichnung: ', style: styles.headerDarkBold},
    {value: 'ANlage dies und das', style: styles.headerDark},
  ],
  [
  ],
  [ {value: 'Bucht: ', style: styles.headerDarkBold},
    {value: 'X3', style: styles.headerDark},
    {value: 'Leiste: ', style: styles.headerDarkBold},
    {value: 'leistenNummer', style: styles.headerDark},
  ],
  [
  ],
];



.....

  for(var k = 0; k<5; k++){
    log("Avorher")
    log(excelData.headingLeistenbelegung)

    excelData.headingLeistenbelegung[4][3].value = k.toString()

    log("Anachher1")
    log(excelData.headingLeistenbelegung[4][3].value)

    log("Anachher2")
    log(excelData.headingLeistenbelegung)
  }
```

the first log shows me the value of 4... why?
I tried already to do an local copy of headingLeistenbelegung, but still the same.

i need this to add the heading to an Excelsheet later

Comment: Probably because `excelData.headingLeistenbelegung` has a value of 4. I'm just guessing, since you haven't show the content of `excelData`.

Comment: export var headingLeistenbelegung is in excelData..and the default value is 'leistenNummer'

Comment: you're running a loop, but you're assigning to `excelData.headingLeistenbelegung[4][3]` every time, so first you set it to 0, then it loops and you overwrite it with 1, then 2, then 3, then 4 and the loops stops. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here

Comment: yes.. but my log shout show me first "1" then "2" ...And i see immediately in the first log "4" and also in the 3 next logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found something similar

[console.log() shows the changed value of a variable before the value actually changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284663/console-log-shows-the-changed-value-of-a-variable-before-the-value-actually-ch)

this

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(excelData.headingLeistenbelegung)))
```

helped me