# Passing params in React Navigation 5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-navigation-v5

I'm trying to pass a few params between a Tab Navigator. Below is the structure of my program. In **bold** are the routes

**App**(Tab Navigator): { **Main**(stack) & **Filter**(screen) }

**Main**(Stack Navigator): { **Home**(screen) & **MediaDetails**(screen) }

I have a *button* on the screen associated with **Filter** which has an **onPress()** function. I'm passing a few params(but let's only consider the param ***to*** for the sake of this question).

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {
    to: this.state.to,
}
```

Now in the screen associated with **Home**, I'm reading the param inside the state like this:

```
state = {
    to: this.props.route.params.to
}
```

Inside ***App.js***, I've set the initial value of ***to*** to be '2020' like this:

```
<Stack.Screen 
    name="Home" 
    component={HomeScreen}                 
    initialParams={{
       to: '2020'
    }}
/>
```

The initial value is indeed set to *2020*. I press the button. Let's say I'm setting ***to*** to *1900*. Just before ***this.props.navigation.navigate*** executes, I **console.log(this.state.to)** the value and it is indeed updated to *1900*. However, as the screen changes to **Home**, the value reverts back to *2020*(observed via console.log)

Could someone point out the cause for this spooky behavior? I've been trying to debug this for many hours with no luck. React Navigation 5 is pretty new as well so couldn't find anything similar online. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you for reading all the way.

**Edit:** Issue has been resolved and full code has been removed!

Comment: Can you post full code?

Comment: Thanks for showing interest. I've included the full code now.

Comment: Use debugger instead of console.log 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284663/console-log-shows-the-changed-value-of-a-variable-before-the-value-actually-ch

Comment: Tried that and also rendering. Doesn't work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by **updating the state** in **shouldComponentUpdate()**.

This bug was due to the state not being updated as the screen remained mounted.

This was possible because of ***ravirajn22*** on GitHub who explained to me the reasoning behind this bug and a possible solution.

**Link to the answer:** https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6863

Comment: can you post that answer or at least a link to it?

Comment: I’ve posted the link now. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

/* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */

```
onPress={() => {
      navigation.navigate('Details', {
        itemId: 86,
        otherParam: 'anything you want here',
      });
    }}
```

/* 2. Get the param */

```
const DetailsScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
   const { itemId } = route.params;
   const { otherParam } = route.params;
   return (
    <View></View>
    );
};
```

for more info: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Comment: if it is class Component how to get param

Answer (score 1):

As it is stated [Here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#passing-params-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator), you can do it like this:

```js
navigation.navigate('otherStackName', {
  screen: 'destinationScreenName',
  params: { user: 'jane' },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In Functional Component write simple logic like this:-

1. In the parent component

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('childRoute', {data_Pass_to_Child: "Hello I am going to child component"})}>
```

2. In the child component

```
const Chat = ({route}) => { 
    console.log(route.params.data_Pass_to_Child);
    return(whatever based on your UI)
}
```

Note:
Replace `childRoute` with *your route name* and also replace data `{data_Pass_to_Child: "Hello I am going to child component"}` with whatever data you want to pass.

Answer (score 0):

send

```
props.navigation.navigate('YourScreenName', {
    your_key: any_value
});
```

receive in ***YourScreenName.js***

```
var valueReceived = props.navigation.state.params.your_key;
```