# Javascript code executes before it have to

Tags: javascript

why does "cars[0].name = 37" executes earlier than it have to?

```js
var cars = [{name: "First"}, {name: "Second"}, {name: "Third"}];
var guns = [];

for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  guns.push(cars[i]);
}

console.log(guns);  // [{name: 37}, {name: "Second"}, {name: "Third"}]

cars[0].name = 37;
```

I've heard about hoisting, does it have something to do with it?

https://jsfiddle.net/r3wu867c/

Comment: Console is showing most updated value

Comment: @brk and how to fix it?

Comment: We can't reproduce your output with the given code.

Comment: You don't have to fix it, it is working properly - the console you're using is just updating the object for you after you change it.

Comment: @Igor I'm running it in jsfiddle

Comment: `I'm running it in jsfiddle` ← Please include that link in your question.

Comment: @Igor ok, done.

Comment: This answer has an explanation for it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24176638/746914

Comment: Your output still looks the same / correct even in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r3wu867c/). It shows 2 calls to `console.log`. The first one shows the same output as the code above, the second (after the `cars[0].name = 37`) shows the updated value.

Comment: @Igor I'm using a browser console, not the site's one

Comment: Execution order can be unpredictable in Javascript because code executes asynchronously.  For example line 3 might execute before line 2 is finished executing - which could create problems if Line 3 expects Line 2 to have finished executing. You can avoid this problem and control the execution order by using Async functions / Await / Promises.

Comment: @gnorman This code is not asynchronous, it is synchronous.