# Reactjs: Statements in called methods are not executed in sequence

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When a list item is clicked, the modifyItem() is called to append a new string to the items array.

From the console logs, it seems that the items array had been modified before the push method (*** below) is even called?? The statements in the function are not executed in sequence?

Appreciate some light shed on this.

Thank you!

### Console Log Output:

Items BEFORE modification 
["1. Click me and check console log", "2. Placeholder", "additonal text"] // ***

Items AFTER modification 
["1. Click me and check console log", "2. Placeholder", "additonal text"]

### App.jsx

```
import List from './List'
import "../styles.css";

export default function App()
{
  const items = ['1. Click me and check console log', '2. Placeholder']

  function modifyItem()
  {
    console.log('Items BEFORE modification')
    console.log(items)
    items.push('additonal text')
    console.log('Items AFTER modification')
    console.log(items)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        { items.map((item, index) =>
        {
          return <List key={index} id={index} modifyItem={modifyItem} text={item} />
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### List.jsx

```
function List(props)
{
  function modifyMe()
  {
    console.log('Start of ModifyMe')
    props.modifyItem(props.index)
    console.log('End of ModifyMe')
  }
  return <li onClick={ modifyMe } >{ props.text }</li>
}
```

[Codesandbox link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-jones-hvriv?file=/src/components/App.js)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [console.log() shows the changed value of a variable before the value actually changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284663/console-log-shows-the-changed-value-of-a-variable-before-the-value-actually-ch)

Comment: Check the behavior with debugger + breakpoint instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please make a copy of the ite

```js
let items = ['1. Click me and check console log', '2. Placeholder'];
    
  console.log('Items BEFORE modification');
  console.log(items);
  items = [...items];
  items.push('3. Additonal text');
  console.log('Items AFTER modification');
  console.log(items);
```

ms before modifying. Here is an example to handle this job.

Comment: I modified the code to make a copy of the items array, however the copied array still contain the additional string before the push() method was called.

Comment: Please check this sandbox code https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-cartwright-swd82?file=/src/components/App.js