# Value below evaluate just now error with console.log

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

can someone help me solve this problem. I dont understand why console log and value of it after evaluate different. As you can see this pic below key SeqNo in console.log has no value but it actually has it [image]

This is my function in component in Angular will return array and will be parameter for other function has above console.log

```
async prepareDetailForSave(allModelSalesTargetDetail) {
        const salesTargetDetailForSave: any = [];
        for (const detail of allModelSalesTargetDetail) {
            await new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
                if (detail.SeqNo === '') {
                    if (detail.Money !== 0) {
                        detail.RSeqNo = this.objMaster.SeqNo;
                        detail.CreateDate = UtilsService.getCurrentDate();
                        detail.ModifiedDate = UtilsService.getCurrentDate();
                        if (this.global.connectionStatus === 'offline') {
                            detail.SeqNo = UtilsService.getLocalSeqno().toString();
                        } else {
                            this.jamService.getInvoiceCode('sales-target-detail').subscribe((res: any) => {
                                detail.SeqNo = res['seqno'];
                            });
                        }
                        salesTargetDetailForSave.push(detail);
                    }
                } else {
                    salesTargetDetailForSave.push(detail);
                }
                resolve();
            });
        }
        return salesTargetDetailForSave;
    }
```

Comment: you should post a concerning code here for more clarity.
my initial assumption is that you are trying to fetch data from the server and might be calling ```console.log``` before the promise is resolved, giving you an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [console.log() shows the changed value of a variable before the value actually changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284663/console-log-shows-the-changed-value-of-a-variable-before-the-value-actually-ch)

Comment: Past code please

Comment: I edit question add code. Pls read again and help me! Thank you guys so much!

Comment: Thank you @sabbir.alam! i will read it maybe it can help me