# Why does this loop repeatedly log the last pair in the array instead of all the pairs?

Tags: node.js, typescript, for-loop, object

I am using Node v16.15.1 and TypeScript v4.7.4

I want to split an object into multiple objects, and then insert each object as a value in another object.
i.e.

```
   {key1:"value1", key2:"value2"}
-> {key1:"value1"} and {key2:"value2"}
-> {key3:"value3", key4:"value4", key5:{key1:"value1"}} and {key3:"value3", key4:"value4", key5:{key2:"value2"}}
```

Below is the code I am using:

```
let a:any = {}
let entries = Object.entries({key1:"value1", key2:"value2"});
for(const el of entries) {
    let b = a;
    b.key = Object.fromEntries(new Map([el]));
    console.log(b.key);
    console.log(b)
}
```

However, the output I get is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3S8t.png).
{key2:"value2"} is in both objects, instead of just the second one.

---

If I use the following code, however, I get the [correct result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrS2a.png):

```
let entries = Object.entries({key1:"value1", key2:"value2"});
for(const el of entries) {
  let b:any = {};
  b.key = Object.fromEntries(new Map([el]));
  console.log(b.key);
  console.log(b)
}
```

The problem with this is that I am not inserting into a blank object, and am passing it as a parameter in a function.

Why does this happen?

How would I be able to fix this?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript, when you do `let a:any = {};` and then `let b = a;` you are assigning to `b` the references of `a` (not the value). So if you update `b`, you are actually updating `a` because both variable are the same.

If you want `b` to be a copy of `a` you should do something like : `let b = {...a}`.

Comment: ah that makes sense. but why does it print different values for b.key and b in the first (or more specifically, anything but the last) iteration?

Comment: The `console.log` is not always reliable, specially in that kind of case for the exact same reason: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48969647/3672560. If you use `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b)))`, you'll get the right value.