# <Link href={`/product/${slug.current}`}> slug.current is not working (slug.current is undefined but when i am doing console.log like this its showing

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, project

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';

import { urlFor } from '../lib/clients';

const Product = ({ product: { image, name, slug, price } }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link href={`/product/${slug.current}`}>
        <div className="product-card">
          <img 
            src={urlFor(image && image[0])}
            width={250}
            height={250}
            className="product-image"
          />
          <p className="product-name">{name}</p>
          <p className="product-price">${price}</p>
        </div>
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Product
```

here is the code

Comment: [Many browsers provide a live view that constantly updates as values change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58885852/5767872)

Comment: Where does `slug` come from? Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though the value of `slug` changes after the `Product` component has been rendered. For this, you might want to not display anything until the value of `slug` is correct, which you can achieve with a React effect hook.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';

import { urlFor } from '../lib/clients';

const Product = ({ product: { image, name, slug, price } }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    // This logs the value of `slug` as it changes
    console.log('value of slug:', slug);
  }, [slug]);

  // This means that nothing is rendered if `slug` is undefined
  if (!slug) return null;

  return (
    <div>
      <Link href={`/product/${slug.current}`}>
        <div className="product-card">
          <img 
            src={urlFor(image && image[0])}
            width={250}
            height={250}
            className="product-image"
          />
          <p className="product-name">{name}</p>
          <p className="product-price">${price}</p>
        </div>
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Product
```