# if I print whole array it works, but if i try to output its first index or any index, there no output or error sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, reader

im reading a txt file from reader object onload and it reads fine but i want to save specific results in an array to later traverse on but it doesn't work with array index given like arr[0], here is my code;

```
function loadData(item) {
    let finalString = new Array();
    let reader = new FileReader();
    var header_read = false, status_index = 0;
    reader.onload = function (progressEvent) {
        var lines = this.result.split("\n");
        for (var line = 0; line < lines.length - 1; line++) {
            var tmpArray = lines[line].split("\t");
            if(line === 0){
                const isStatus = (element) => element.toLowerCase() === 'status';
                var cur_index = tmpArray.findIndex(isStatus); 
            }else{
                finalString.push(tmpArray[cur_index]);
            }
        }
    };
    reader.readAsText(item);
    for(let try1 in finalString){
        console.log(finalString[try1]);
    }
}
```

I've tried many things all around the internet but nothing seems so work for me

Comment: You are not handling the fact that reading is _async_ correctly here. By the time you try to loop over the contents of finalString there at the end, that array has not been populated with anything yet.

Comment: [console.log() shows the changed value of a variable before the value actually changes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11284663)

Answer (score 0):

finalString is an array, you are using the for-in construct which is used for objects... You better use for-of.

```
let finalString = new Array();
function loadData(item) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    var header_read = false, status_index = 0;
    reader.onload = function (progressEvent) {
        var lines = this.result.split("\n");
        for (var line = 0; line < lines.length - 1; line++) {
            var tmpArray = lines[line].split("\t");
            if(line === 0){
                const isStatus = (element) => element.toLowerCase() === 'status';
                var cur_index = tmpArray.findIndex(isStatus); 
            }else{
                finalString.push(tmpArray[cur_index]);
            }
        }
        for(let str of finalString){
            console.log(str);
        }
    };
    reader.readAsText(item);
}
console.log(finalString); // EMPTY
setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log(finalString); // Waited 2 seconds, should be OK.
},2000);
```

As @adiga pointed out, you also need to make sure you log the variable from the onload function since before that, the variable will not contain the result yet.

Comment: it only works for console.log(finalString), every other method ive tried but no output

Comment: @Hamza-ally This answer will not fix your issue. You need to do this looping side the `onload` handler. after the `for(var line = 0; ...) {}` block.

Comment: @adiga is right! I overlooked that part... The console.log is gonna be executed before the variable is incremented... I edited the answer.

Comment: yes it work in the handler but is there any other way to make it work outside its scope

Comment: Yes, if you define the variable outside the scope. But even then, you'll need to console.log once the onload has ran... I've edited to show this.

Comment: well onload works one up for suggestions