# Why does the debugger apply the mutating methods before they are called?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

As you can see below, even though the array is logged before the mutating method is applied, the debugger still shows it as already being applied. However, its elements and properties when called specifically still return correctly:

[image]

If I add a breakpoint before the methods, then it is correct. If I continue then the result doesn't change.

[image]

I've read about [Copying methods and mutating methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#copying_methods_and_mutating_methods) but still don't get why this is the case.

Is this a bug of VS Code or something?

```js
const array = ["cat","dog","mouse"]
console.log('array', array);
console.log('array[0] :>> ', array[0]);
console.log('array.length :>> ', array.length);

array.splice(0, 1)
// array.push('bat')
debugger
```

Comment: Now try it logging `JSON.stringify(array)`

Comment: `["cat","dog","mouse"]`

Comment: What does that suggest about logging objects?

Comment: a bug of VS Code?

Comment: Or console.log is dynamic and reflects the object as-it-is, rather than as-it-was. That's what `JSON.stringify` does.

Comment: if so, then why does applying non-mutating methods to the object itself, e.g. `array = array.slice(0,1)` doesn't change the object?

Comment: Same thing happens in browsers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11284663/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/23429203/3001761. _"why does applying non-mutating methods... doesn't change the object"_ - because they're non-mutating.

Comment: Non-mutating methods don't change the object by definition.

Comment: @DaveNewton I know that they don't change the object, but isn't that assigning the result to the original object changing it as well?

Comment: That changes what `array` references, not the object. The `console.log(array)` line isn't re-evaluated--the console displays the original reference.

Comment: The outcome of `console.log()` is colored in blue. The other information that you can see in the console is probably an enhancement of the browser (VSCode is backed by Chromium) that displays dynamic data in the console, based on what objects were passed to `console.log()`. It mixes the behaviour of the console (which shows the data as it looked like when it has been printed) with the behaviour of the "Variables" window, which evaluates each expression every time the application is stopped in the debugger.