# Javascript unexpected results .map() or .forEach()

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an unexpected results when trying to use .map() or .forEach() methods. It seems that they are hoisted, or queued differently... I would expect the console.log() to run first but the .forEach() and or .map() always seem to run first. I'd love to know why and how folks are dealing with this.

```js
let circles = [
  { params: [200, 350], used: false },
  { params: [1300, 1000], used: false },
  { params: [450, 1025], used: false }
];

console.log(circles);
// OUTPUTS: [{ params: [200, 350], used: true}, ...]

circles.forEach(circle => {
  circle.used = true;
});
```

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284663/console-log-shows-the-changed-value-of-a-variable-before-the-value-actually-ch

Comment: The browsers `lazy` logger :),  A lot of solutions give -> `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))`, but this loses the nice formatting in the browsers console.  A much nicer option is `console.log(structuredClone(circles));`

Comment: ^^ Also `structuredClone` will serialize more things than JSON, eg. `Int8Array`, `undefined` `NaN` etc.