# A 2-dimensional array (React state) sometimes gets filled with zeroes. How do I solve this?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I have a two-dimensional array declared as React state:

```
const [adjacencyMatrix, setAdjacencyMatrix] = useState([
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
  ]);
```

And I also have a number input for each cell of this table:

```
<input
            type="number"
            value={adjacencyMatrix[rowNode.id - 1][columnNode.id - 1]}
            min={0}
            step={1}
            onChange={(event) => {
              const newAdjacencyMatrix = [...adjacencyMatrix];
              let difference = +event.target.value - adjacencyMatrix[rowNode.id - 1][columnNode.id - 1];
              console.log("Difference:", difference);
              console.log("old:", adjacencyMatrix);
              console.log("new:", newAdjacencyMatrix);
              newAdjacencyMatrix[rowNode.id - 1][columnNode.id - 1] = 
              adjacencyMatrix[rowNode.id - 1][columnNode.id - 1] + difference;
              if (rowNode.id !== columnNode.id) {
                newAdjacencyMatrix[columnNode.id - 1][rowNode.id - 1] = 
                newAdjacencyMatrix[rowNode.id - 1][columnNode.id - 1];
              }
              setAdjacencyMatrix(newAdjacencyMatrix);
            }
            }
            id={`adjacency${rowNode.id}${columnNode.id}`}
          />
```

But unfortunately, when I change a number, those changes are displayed correctly in UI, but sometimes the matrix becomes filled with zeroes (I can observe it in React DevTools), and when I change another cell next time, the rest of cells become filled with zeroes. How do I solve this?

For example, when I increase the number in one cell to 1, then to 2, the UI matrix changes as follows:
0 1 0
1 0 0
0 0 0

0 2 0
2 0 0
0 0 0

But in React DevTools I see this:
0 1 0
1 0 0
0 0 0

0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0

And when I change the value in first row and last column, the matrix in user interface looks like this:

0 0 1
0 0 0
1 0 0

Whereas I want it to be:

0 2 1
2 0 0
1 0 0

Comment: Two things jump out: 1. You're breaking one of the rules of React state by directly mutating the subarrays inside the array. You need to copy not just the outer array, but any inner array you modify, for the UI to reliably reflect the contents of those arrays. 2. I suggest ruling out [this console behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284663/console-log-shows-the-changed-value-of-a-variable-before-the-value-actually-ch) by changing your log lines to output JSON, like this: `console.log("old:", JSON.stringify(adjacencyMatrix));` That way you're getting a point-in-time snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

In the following line you are trying to compute a new state based on the old state, and also attempting to rebuild an array of arrays by spreading.

```
const newAdjacencyMatrix = [...adjacencyMatrix];
```

If you want to update the state based on its previous condition then you should utilize the updater function of setState: [React Docs: Updating State based on previous](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state).

The second issue is because spreading performs a shallow copy, only the top-level elements are copied, and because arrays are not primitives only the reference to the array will be copied and not the array itself.

The following could resolve both portions together.

```
onChange={(event) => {
    setAdjacencyMatrix((prevMatrix) => {
      const newMatrix = prevMatrix.map((subArray) => {
        return [...subArray]
      })
    // The rest of your logic here //
    })
}
```