# How can I access Element in HTML Collection Even After DOM Load?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an issue where even though the DOM is fully loaded, and an html collection appears, when I try to access the 0 position of that collection, it comes back as undefined.  I am unsure why if it appears in the collection with a length of 1, that it doesn't find the single element I am looking for:

```
  const scrollbarElements = document.getElementsByClassName(
    "ag-body-horizontal-scroll-viewport"
  );

  const doThing = () => {
    console.log("All the elements:");
    console.log(scrollbarElements);
    console.log("Elements at the 0 position:");
    console.log(scrollbarElements[0]);
  };

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", doThing());
```

Here is the console output:
[image: Here is the console output]

As you can see from the console, scrollbarElements has one element in it, but when I try to access that element directly, it comes back as undefined.  This is all running after the DOM is loaded, so I cannot figure out why that single element can't be accessed.

Comment: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", doThing());` **calls** `doThing` and passes its return value into `addEventListener`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`. So `doThing` is called before `addEventListener` and before `DOMContentLoaded` fires (presumably, given the error you're getting; it depends on where/how your script is loaded). See the linked question's answers for what to do (most likely: remove the `()` on `doThing`: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", doThing);`.)

Comment: I thought that could be it, but unfortunately if I remove the call () then nothing is logged, so presumably it doesn't run at all.  I have tried this syntax as well `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => doThing());` but that also does not call it as expected.  I also tried adding the event listener onto the window object but that did not work either.  I wonder if DOMContentLoaded just isn't fired?  I am not sure how I would confirm that.

Comment: If `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", doThing);` doesn't work, then yes, either A) `DOMContentLoaded` isn't firing (though I've never heard of that happening), or B) you're adding the handler *after* the event has fired (more likely). You could allow for (B) by doing `if (document.readyState !== "complete" && document.readyState !== "interactive") { /*...add the event handler */ } else { /*...call your function directly, the document is already ready... */ }` You might also look into using modules, since modules are automatically deferred.

Comment: (I didn't remember offhand, but it looks like [there are only three values for `document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState), so you could just use `if (document.readyState === "loading") { /*...add the event handler...*/ } else { /*...call your function directly...*/ }`.)

Comment: Thank you, yes I actually found that document.readyState possibility to test it and it seems that everything I am running is after DOMContentLoaded was already fired.  Unfortunately that confuses me even more... if the DOM content is already loaded, and it is then able to access the HTML collection I am looking at, I still don't understand why it can't access the 0 element of that collection if everything has already been loaded in the DOM.

Comment: From your screenshot, it's clear the collection is empty when the function is called (see the `[]` on the summary, before the expansion [later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284663/console-log-shows-the-changed-value-of-a-variable-before-the-value-actually-ch) showing an element in it). So the element would appear to be added *after* document ready, by scripting code.

Comment: Thank you, yes, that seems to be the case.  If I set a timeout on doThing() it shows what I am expecting so it must be manipulated somewhere after the DOM is loaded.