# Retrieve children Added up to the point

Tags: javascript, html, svg, dom

Is there a way to retrieve only the children added up-to a specific point. For example, I have created `rect and circle` and I am executing `fnTwo` before I have added a `path` with the the hope that it returns only `rect and circle`. But it returns all the children; e.g. `rect, circle +path`; even though path was added after. Is there a way for me execute `fnTwo` to get the children that were added up to that point in time.

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
const element = ['rect', 'circle'];

//fn for append
const fnOne = (element) => {
    const child = document.createElementNS(svgns, element);
    svg.append(child);

}
//append all elements
for (const elements of element) {
    const element = elements;
    fnOne(element)
};
// get all the children elements **up to this point in time**
const fnTwo = (element) => {
    const children = element.children;
  //do something with the children
    console.log(children); //brings all children added before + after
}

const children = fnTwo(svg);
//add a path to test if it is retrieved through fnTwo
const childThree = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'path');
svg.append(childThree);
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <svg>      
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your criteria of a "point"? how do you define at which point it should stop gathering the children?

Comment: Till the next child is added to the SVG.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [console.log() shows the changed value of a variable before the value actually changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284663/console-log-shows-the-changed-value-of-a-variable-before-the-value-actually-ch)

Comment: If `fnTwo` is just for console logging the object up to that point, then @vanowm's answer is totally valid. But if `fnTwo` is just doing some synchronized task and it's not affecting the children the way you don't want, then just go ahead and use the children reference directly. In `fnTwo` when you retreived the object it **is** the object up to that point. You can see that if you open the console terminal on your browser then refresh the page.

Comment: @SyndRain other words, if you simply iterate the array directly in `fnTwo`, aka process each child individually with a `for` loop, you don't need create a copy of it, this will increase performance.

Comment: Yes nice conclusion! Or if it's just for debugging, opening the browser console before hand works as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is because you return original "array" of children, what you need to do is to return a copy:

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
const element = ['rect', 'circle'];

//fn for append
const fnOne = (element) => {
    const child = document.createElementNS(svgns, element);
    svg.append(child);

}
//append all elements
for (const elements of element) {
    const element = elements;
    fnOne(element)
};
// get all the children elements **up to this point in time**
const fnTwo = (element) => {
    const children = [...element.children]; //shallow copy of the array
  //do something with the children
    console.log(children); //brings all children added before + after
}

const children = fnTwo(svg);
//add a path to test if it is retrieved through fnTwo
const childThree = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'path');
svg.append(childThree);
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <svg>      
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```