JavaScript Array not filling correctly with push
I want to send multiple XMLHttpRequests to my server, collect the results in an array, then use this array to populate the HTML of the target element, in this case a Popover.
My code is a mixture of pure JS and JQuery and looks like this:
$('.commentary-word').on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
        var popElement = '#' + $(this).attr('aria-describedby');
        var comm_urns = $(this).attr('comm-passages').split('%');
        var comm_passages = [];
        comm_urns.forEach(function(comm_urn) {
            var urn = comm_urn.split(';')[0]
            var target = comm_urn.split(';')[1]
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4) {
                    if (this.status == 200) {
                        comm_passages.push(this.responseText)
                    } else {
                        alert("Passage " + urn + ':' + target + " not found")
                    }
                }
            };
            request.open('GET', '/snippet/' + urn + '/subreference/' + target + '?source=ntPassage', true);
            request.send()
        });
        $(popElement).children('.popover-body').html(comm_passages.join('<br>'));
    })

I was expecting that the .popover-body would be filled with the joined results from the multiple XHR results. Instead I get an empty string.
When I print comm_passages to the console, it looks like this:
Array []​
0: "CJHNT Commentary on 1 Timothy 1.1"​
1: "CJHNT Commentary on 1 Timothy 1.1a"​
length: 2​

And when I try to access, e.g., comm_passages[0] I get undefined. I don't know enough to figure out if this is a problem with the interaction between JQuery and JS or whether something else is going on.
Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

comm_passages.join runs before the ajax requests have completed.  You're trying to eat  your pizza before it's been delivered.

easiest fix - use fetch and Promise.all

@fdomn-m I thought this could be a problem. But if I put console.log(comm_passages) before the comm_passages.join command, I see that comm_passages has content.

The issue there is that the console evaluates the value at the time you expand it, not at the time it enters the console - it's a "live value".  Add your console.log then put debugger; directly after - this will jump into the debugger and pause the ajax requests and you can then expand your console.log and you'll see it's empty at that point.

@fdomn-m Ah, OK. Then I will implement the solution from Jaromanda X. Thanks for your help.

No, console.log is deceiving in this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284663/console-log-shows-the-changed-value-of-a-variable-before-the-value-actually-ch  Do console.log(JSON.stringify(comm_passages)) and you will see, it logs an empty array
